# How do you use a file as input with Node's child_process.spawn?

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal

In my `gulpfile.js` I have this `spawn()` which triggers a `mysqldump`:

```
let mysqldump = spawn('mysqldump', [
  '-v',
  '-u',
  'my_db_name',
  '--password=' + process.env.MY_PRODUCTION_PASSWORD,
  '-h',
  'my_domain.com',
  'my_db_name',
  '< ' + dump_filename
], {
  stdio: 'inherit'
});
```

Although I get an error message about that last part. It says `Couldn't find table: "< Development-dump.sql"` which leads me to believe the last line there isn't using the dump file as input. How do I get `spawn` to use a file as input like this?

Comment: Do you intend to restore the database from the dump file?

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because the `spawn` command cannot parse input. You'll need to write the dump file to the `input` stream of the `spawn` command:

```
// Define the spawned process without the input
let mysqldump = spawn('mysqldump', [
  '-v',
  '-u',
  'my_db_name',
  '--password=' + process.env.MY_PRODUCTION_PASSWORD,
  '-h',
  'my_domain.com',
  'my_db_name'
]);

// Write the dump file to the input stream.
mysqldump.stdin.write(//path to dump file);
mysqldump.stdin.end();
```

Comment: It's the same message (`mysqldump: Couldn't find table: "> Development-dump.sql"`). `<` works normally when I do a `child_process.exec` but it just doesn't work with `child_process.spawn`. I'm trying to import the database from a dump on my development computer.

Comment: Thank you for making the clarification. The answer assumed you wanted to dump the database to a file. I'll update it now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to use `<` to redirect standard input, the following code may works.

```
let mysqldump = spawn([
  'mysqldump',
  '-v',
  '-u',
  'my_db_name',
  '--password=' + process.env.MY_PRODUCTION_PASSWORD,
  '-h',
  'my_domain.com',
  'my_db_name',
  '< ' + dump_filename
].join(' '), {
  stdio: 'inherit',
  shell: true
});
```